# Is there any significance in letting the user manually write the receiver parameter in method arguments in Java?

Tags: java, jls

It is possible to manually write the receiver parameter of an instance method as below.

```
class A {
    public void test(A this) { }
}
```

Is there any purpose to write as above? Then, I tried to use it in the following way.

```
A a1 = new A();
A a2 = new A();
a1.test(a2);
```

Obviously the above is a compilation error. Why allow the user to write such syntax when it has no practical use. Is there any purpose for manually writing it?

Comment: Yes, the duplicate answers my question @SotiriosDelimanolis. I wonder how you find these duplicates. I clearly did a good Google search and the SO's "similar to your question suggestions" were not even close.

Comment: I knew the quote from the JLS, so I looked that up directly with `site:stackoverflow.com`, which I wouldn't expect someone asking to do. But I also just tried with `java purpose of receiver parameter` on Google and the post came up as well.